# Application of Holder's Inequality: $\mathbb{E}|X| \ge \frac 1{\mathbb{E}\left[X^4\right]^{1/2}}$

Tags: probability, expectation, holder-inequality

> Show that if  $\mathbb{E}\!\left[X^2\right] =1$ and $\mathbb{E}\!\left[X^4\right] < \infty$, then
>   $$\mathbb{E}|X| \ge \dfrac 1{\mathbb{E}\left[X^4\right]^{1/2}}$$

I have tried to write$X^2=|X|^r \cdot |X|^{2-r}$.
However I run into trouble using Holder's Inequality when taking the expectation of the expression.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Do you want the solution (as the fact that you just restated the question with no thoughts nor attempt of your own seems to suggest), or to understand how to get to it?

Comment: Sorry, new on here. Yes, I would like some help in arriving at the solution.

Comment: Here we go then. My advice: don't look at the spoiler before you finish by yourself.

Comment: @ClementC. I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Thank you.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Very detailed hint:** from your assumptions, it is clear you want to prove
$$
1=\mathbb{E}[|X|^2]^\alpha \leq \mathbb{E}[|X|^4]^{1/2}\mathbb{E}[|X|] \tag{1}
$$
using Holder's inequality, for some suitable choice of $\alpha>0$. Homogeneity *(like in physics)* tells you that $\alpha$ must satisfy
$$
2\alpha = 4\cdot\frac{1}{2}+1
$$
since otherwise you can replace $|X|$ in the LHS by $\lambda|X|$, and varying $\lambda>0$ to make it goes to either $0$ or $\infty$, you could violate the inequality. So this settles it: $\alpha = 3/2$, and we want to prove
$$
\mathbb{E}[|X|^2]^{3/2} \leq \mathbb{E}[|X|^4]^{1/2}\mathbb{E}[|X|] \tag{2}
$$
Well, that's not convenient for Holder, since we would like the LHS to be to the power $1$. Let's arrange that: we want to prove
$$
\mathbb{E}[|X|^2] \leq \mathbb{E}[|X|^4]^{1/3}\mathbb{E}[|X|]^{2/3} \tag{3}
$$
That begins to look like something. Apparently, we want to apply Holder's inequality with $1/p=1/3$, $1/q=2/3$ *(conveniently, this gives $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$, so everything looks consistent so far)*. So $$p=3,q=3/2$$ it is.

To do so, we need to write $|X|^4 = (|X|^{4/p})^p=(|X|^{4/3})^p$ and $|X|=(|X|^{1/q})^q=(|X|^{2/3})^{q}$. Again, *so far so good*: since on the LHS we have $|X|^2$, and 
$$
|X|^2 = |X|^{4/3}\cdot |X|^{2/3}\,.
$$
Can you finish?

**Spoiler** (solution):

> $$1=\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \mathbb{E}[|X|^{4/3}|X|^{2/3}] \leq \mathbb{E}[(|X|^{4/3})^{3}]^{1/3} \mathbb{E}[(|X|^{2/3})^{3/2}]^{2/3} = \mathbb{E}[(|X|^4]^{1/3} \mathbb{E}[|X|]^{2/3}$$so, taking everything to the power $3/2$,$$1 = 1^{3/2} \leq \mathbb{E}[(|X|^4]^{1/2} \mathbb{E}[|X|]$$

Comment: Yes I believe I can finish. Thank you very much.

Comment: @FFS You're welcome.